# addons for Firefox for Android - Disable menu item?

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on, fennec

I've looked at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Mobile/Creating_a_User_Interface) and the [example](https://github.com/mfinkle/skeleton-addon-fxandroid/blob/master/bootstrap.js) but it only shows ways to add/remove menu items, but not disable. Is it not possible or is there a way to do this? If so, can you please provide me a link to the full API(if there is one).

Comment: Did you try asking at http://client01.chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org&channel=%23mobile

Answer (score 0):

Did you try watching this addon source code? Sometimes some thing are the same in mobile: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/menu-editor/

There is a lot of people who can help you here:
http://client01.chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org&channel=%23mobile

Answer (score 0):

You can use NativeWindow.menu.add(...) to add the menu, then use NativeWindow.menu.update(...) to disable it. See the docs for examples:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Mobile/API/NativeWindow/menu/update